# using a variable to referance another in a class in PHP

Tags: php

so here's a cut down version of my code:

```
class lookAClass
{
 public $pageTitle;

 public function add()
 {
  $tmp = 'just some filler text &lt;[pageTitle]&gt; and some more text';
  echo preg_replace_callback('&lt;\&lt;\[(.*)\]\&gt;&gt;', array(&$this, 'parseAdd'), $tmp);
 }

 private function parseAdd($matches)
 {
  return $this->$matches[1];
 }


}

$main = new lookAClass();

$main->add();
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is replace "<[pageTitle]>" with $this->pageTitle

I know `$this->$matches[1]` is incorrect but I can't seem to find how to make the connection.

Comment: This should have thrown a clear error. That regex is completely broken. If you didn't see an error, increase your error reporting level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
echo str_replace('<[pageTitle]>', $this->pageTitle, $tmp);
```

Comment: I would have gone that route except I don't want to have to check for however many <[..]> variables I may have.. I'd rather just have it use the inside text of the <[..]> to reference the variable I need if possible?

Comment: ..  stupid mistake on my part..  I forgot I was using a global in the real code...